# How to prevent cells from indenting when using custom swipe actions in edit mode?

Tags: ios, tableview

I'm trying to implement two cells, one that can be deleted by swiping, and one that **can't** be deleted, but has swipe actions the other way.

This is what it looks like now:

[image: swiping]

I don't want the middle cell to be indented when clicking Edit.
Without any custom code, all cells would show this red circle and get a delete-button, but I have added a few lines of code to prevent that.

This code will set all cells without a leading or trailing swipe action to not become editable, which explains the bottom cell in the gif. I have to include the leading swipe actions to this, because if the cell isn't `editable`, then I can't swipe at all.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    let vm = sections[indexPath.section].viewModels[indexPath.row]
    return vm.leadingSwipeActions != nil || vm.trailingSwipeActions != nil
}
```

The following code will prevent the middle cell from showing the red circle.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell.EditingStyle {
    return sections[indexPath.section].viewModels[indexPath.row].trailingSwipeActions == nil ? .none : .delete
}
```

If I don't pass `.none` for the cell with leading actions, then it would show the red circle **AND** it would even show a default deletion-swipe. I don't want the ability to delete this row!

How can I prevent the middle cell from indenting, while still retaining the ability to swipe it?

Comment: Have you tried this method: `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614873-tableview?language=objc

Comment: @Zaya Jesus christ.. It was that easy. You might as well post it as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method seems to work! `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool` 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614873-tableview?language=objc